# NSKeyedArchiver: key returning nil - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, null, nskeyedarchiver

I'm having some issues here. I'm trying to store some information with NSKeyedArchiver, but when I run the app, I get: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**.

> Apple docs says: "If you invoke one of the decode... methods of this
>   class using a key that does not exist in the archive, a non-positive
>   value is returned. This value varies by decoded type. For example, if
>   a key does not exist in an archive, decodeBoolForKey: returns NO,
>   decodeIntForKey: returns 0, and **decodeObjectForKey: returns nil.**"

My key for decoding the object is returning nil as the docs says, but I have no idea why.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, sendDetailsToMVCDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, NSCoding {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var namesListArray:[String] = []
    var imagesListArray:[UIImage] = []

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.namesListArray = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("namesListArray") as! [String] **//HERE IS THE CRASH LINE**
        self.imagesListArray = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("imagesListArray") as! [UIImage]
    }

    override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.namesListArray, forKey: "namesListArray")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.imagesListArray, forKey: "imagesListArray")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let dir = getUserDir()
        let archive = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-namesListArray"
        if let loaded: AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(archive) {
            self.namesListArray = (loaded as? Array)!
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    }

    func sendDetailsToMVC (name: String, image: UIImage) {

        namesListArray.append(name)
        let dir = getUserDir()
        let archive = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-namesListArray"
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(namesListArray, toFile: archive)

        imagesListArray.append(image)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func getUserDir() -> String {
        let userDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        return userDir[0] as! String
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return namesListArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let row = indexPath.row
        let name = namesListArray[row]
        println("\(row)/")
        let image = imagesListArray[row]
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
        cell.imageView!.image = image

        return cell
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject) {
            if segue.identifier == "goToInfoVC" {
                if let navigation = navigationController {
                    navigation.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "newReciep" {
            var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
            vc.delegateDetails = self
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any idea? Thanks in advance!

[image: Error pic]

**EDIT 1**
[image]

Comment: This `self.namesListArray = (loaded as? Array)!` looks wrong. Did you mean `self.namesListArray = (loaded as? [String])!`? And what if the cast didn't work?

Comment: I did as you said and the error persists. Keeps getting nil.

Comment: Updated the questions with log error

Comment: When you load for the first time there is nothing to decode. You should check if the array is nil after decoding and set it to an empty array in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the init to this:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    if let namesList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("namesListArray") as? [String] {
        namesListArray = namesList
    } else {
        namesListArray = [String]
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code with the solution:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, sendDetailsToMVCDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, NSCoding {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var namesListArray:[String] = []
    var imagesListArray:[UIImage] = []
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        if let namesList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("namesListArray") as? [String] {
            namesListArray = namesList
        } else {
            namesListArray = [String]()
        }
        if let imagesList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("imagesListArray") as? [UIImage] {
            imagesListArray = imagesList
        } else {
            imagesListArray = [UIImage]()
        }
    }
    
    override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.namesListArray, forKey: "namesListArray")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.imagesListArray, forKey: "imagesListArray")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let dir = getUserDir()
        let archiveName = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-namesListArray"
        if let loaded: AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(archiveName) {
            self.namesListArray = (loaded as? [String])!
        }
        let archiveImage = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-imagesListArray"
        if let loaded: AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(archiveImage) {
            self.imagesListArray = (loaded as? [UIImage])!
        }

    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    }
    
    func sendDetailsToMVC (name: String, image: UIImage) {
        
        namesListArray.append(name)
        imagesListArray.append(image)
        
        let dir = getUserDir()
        let archiveName = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-namesListArray"
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(namesListArray, toFile: archiveName)
        let archiveImage = "\(dir)/iRecipeList-imagesListArray"
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(imagesListArray, toFile: archiveImage)
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func getUserDir() -> String {
        let userDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        return userDir[0] as! String
    }
    
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return namesListArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let row = indexPath.row
        let name = namesListArray[row]
        println("\(row)/")
        let image = imagesListArray[row]
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
        cell.imageView!.image = image
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject) {
            if segue.identifier == "goToInfoVC" {
                if let navigation = navigationController {
                    navigation.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "newReciep" {
            var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
            vc.delegateDetails = self
        }
    }
}
```